# How to show time in hour,minute and second format in angular

Tags: angular, date, date-conversion, date-pipe

Date is coming as 00:00:07 but I want to show in UI as 0h 0m 0s.

Is there a way to show like this ?
I tried split function working fine but don't want to use split is there any library available?

Comment: do you have date as well like "04 Dec 1995 00:12:00" or just time??

Comment: just time 00:12:00 @ShlokNangia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use split then following way can be used

```js
var s = "10:03:07"

parts = s.match(/(\d+)\:(\d+):(\d+)/)

console.log(parts[1] + 'h ' + parts[2] + 'm ' + parts[3] + 's')
```

or you can create a new Date (i.e. today's date) with that exact time

```
d.setHours(parts[1])
d.setMinutes(parts[2])
d.setSeconds(part[3])
alert(d)
```

Comment: thanks for your respone..but I'm using angular 9 cant use this code !